# Parsing array value with PHP in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I want to parse an array with PHP's foreach loop to get the object names and values inside the 'ques' array.I want
  [image]

```
[
 {
 "ques": [
{
    "name": "comment",
    "value": "comment me for the reason",
    "sur_id": "1",
    "user_id": "admin@gmail.com",
    "pagename": "question_response"
},
{
    "name": "check-box[]",
    "value": "1"
},
{
    "name": "radio",
    "value": "radio 2"
},
{
    "name": "yes",
    "value": "no"
}

]
"ques":[
{
    "name": "date",
    "value": "2015-10-23"
    "user_id": "admin1@gmail.com",  
},
{
    "name": "select-deopdown",
    "value": ""
},
{
    "name": "true",
    "value": "false"
},
{
    "name": "number",
    "value": "55"
 }
 ]
}
]
```

I want to separate the name,value and user_id  from the 'ques' array:

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$content = $fetch['CONTENT_VALUES'];
// print_r($content);
$content_value= mb_convert_encoding($content ,"UTF-8");
$datas = json_decode($content, true);
 foreach($datas->ques as $values)
 {
     echo $values->value . "\n";
      print_r($values);
 }
 $test[] = array('ques' =>  $datas ,'answer'=>$values);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following code.Thanks for 3 of them to guide by giving ideas.

```
$datas = json_decode($content, true);
foreach($datas as $values)
 {
 $name = $values['name'];
 $value = $values['value'];
 $user_id = $values['user_id'];
 $test[]= array('user'=>$user,'name'=>$name,'value'=>$value);
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make three different array for each value then create three blank array and then storing corresponding values into them in foreach . Am giving you a common example below

```
$name = array(); 
$values= array(); 
$users = array();   
foreach($datas->ques as $values) {
    $name[] = $values->name;   
    $values[] = $values->value; 
    $users[] = !empty($values->user_id) ? $values->user_id : '';
}
```

and further you can modify according your need.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for saving my day @Shyam. This foreach loop really helped me without this i may waste the rest of my life figuring out error in my code!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($datas->ques as $values)
 {
     $name = $values['name'];
     $value = $values['value'];
     $user_id = $values['user_id'];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
This could help
```

`$data = json_decode($json);`
`$result = [];`
`foreach($data as $row)`
`{`
 `foreach($row as $k => $v)`
`{`
`$i = 0;`
`foreach($v as $key => $val)`
`{`
`foreach($val as $k1 => $v1)`
`{`
`$result[$i][$k1] = $v1;`
`}`
`$i++;`
`}`
`}`
`}`

`echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: $json contains your data that you have shown. $results contains many rows in it . in each row keys are name, value and user_id with its respective values. for you to understand the structure of $result, i have included the echo json_encode($result); try running the entire code